# how can users upload file into Django model?

Tags: django

With these codes, I want each user to be able to upload their own file in their own model

forms.py:

```
class sp_UserNewOrderForm(forms.Form):
    file= forms.FileField()
```

models.py:

```
class sp_Order(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.username


class sp_OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(sp_Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file= models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order.owner.username
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_user_order(request):
    new_order_form = sp_UserNewOrderForm(request.POST or None)

    if new_order_form.is_valid():
        order = sp_Order.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).first()
        if order is None:
            order = sp_Order.objects.create(owner_id=request.user.id)

        file= new_order_form.cleaned_data.get('file')
        order.sp_orderdetail_set.create(file=file)
        # todo: redirect user to user panel
        # return redirect('/user/orders')

        return redirect('/')

    return redirect('/')
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/add_sp">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.count }}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary container">
          upload
     </button>
 </form>
```

But these codes do not create the model. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in this line:
`order = sp_Order.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).first()`

I think you should replace `owner_id = request.user.id` with `owner = request.user`

`owner_id` is not an attribute of the model you're trying to filter or create

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `request.FILES` when instantiating the form for the `POST` request.

```py
def add_user_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         new_order_form = sp_UserNewOrderForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         if new_order_form.is_valid():
             order = sp_Order.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id).first()
             if order is None:
                 order = sp_Order.objects.create(owner_id=request.user.id)

             file= new_order_form.cleaned_data.get('file')
             order.sp_orderdetail_set.create(file=file)
             # todo: redirect user to user panel
             # return redirect('/user/orders')

    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: still it does not upload file to model